# How to log the Response Body content, in RestAssuredWebTestClient, when I am using ResponseSpecification?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, junit5, rest-assured

### 1) Problem Description:

- I am using a RestAssuredWebTestClient, Spring WebFlux and JUnit 05;
- I have a 01 RestAssured ResponseSpecification
- This “ResponseSpecification Method” checks the Response ContentType

### 2) My Goal:

- Make the “ResponseSpecification” generates the 'Response Body log', in the log-console of all tests;

### 3) Code:

**3.1) Current behaviour:**

- the “ResponseSpecification Method” IS NOT logging the 'Response Body' content for any test.

```java
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RestAssureSpecs {

  final private static Long MAX_TIMEOUT = 15000L;
  final private static ContentType JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = ContentType.JSON;

  public static ResponseSpecification responseSpecs() {

    ResponseSpecBuilder responseSpecBuilder = new ResponseSpecBuilder();

    responseSpecBuilder
         .expectResponseTime(lessThanOrEqualTo(MAX_TIMEOUT))
         .expectContentType(JSON_CONTENT_TYPE)
         .expectHeader("Content-Type",String.valueOf(JSON_CONTENT_TYPE))
         .log(LogDetail.BODY) //<<< is not working
         .build();

    return responseSpecBuilder;
  }
}
```

---

### 4) Question:

- How Can I log 'Response Body' content in the terminal console, in order to repeat this behaviour in ALL TESTS, using ResponseSpecification?

---

*Thanks a lot for any help*

Answer (score 0):

It seems no way to set log statically for all tests in RestAssuredWebTestClient.
Two ways can help a little bit.

1. Using `enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails`, only log if fail validation.

```
RestAssuredWebTestClient.config = new RestAssuredWebTestClientConfig()
        .logConfig(new LogConfig(captor, true)
                .enableLoggingOfRequestAndResponseIfValidationFails(BODY));
```

2. log after each request.

```
given()
        .standaloneSetup(new PostController())
        .param("name", "Johan")
        .when()
        .post("/greetingPost")
        .then()
        .log()
        .body();
```